# Django how to reconnect after DatabaseError: query timeout

Tags: database, django, postgresql, orm

I have a stand-alone script that reads/writes from/to Postgre using Django ORM.

I get this error occasionally

> DatabaseError: query timeout server
>   closed the connection unexpectedly
>           This probably means the server terminated abnormally
>           before or while processing the request.

I need to re-establish the connection and retry the processing code in the script, but can't seem to find a way. The following code raises 'InterfaceError: connection already closed' on retry, so it doesn't work.

```
for repeat in range(5):
    try:
        .....................PROCESSING CODE...................
    except DatabaseError, e:
        time.sleep(30)
    else:
        break
else:
    return
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 36):

I have a similar need for recreating the database connection and I'm trying the following black magic to reset the connection in django 1.3:

```
from django.db import connection
connection.connection.close()
connection.connection = None
```

I don't have PostgreSQL handy to try this out, but it seems to work for MySQL and sqlite at least. Also, if you're using multi-db, you're going to have to perform this step on your specific connection from the django.db.connections dictionary.

Comment: I am not bothered by the problem anymore. If someone else verified this answer to be correct solution, I will mark it. Thank you for answering.

Comment: @kakarukeys This works for me. (Django 1.4 and using postgresql)

Comment: Works for me as well in the same setup as seyeong jeong.

Comment: Working for me with django 1.5 and postgresql 9.3 :)