# InterfaceError: connection already closed (using django + celery + Scrapy)

Tags: python, django, scrapy, celery

I am getting this when using a Scrapy parsing function (that can take till 10 minutes sometimes) inside a Celery task.

I use:
- Django==1.6.5
- django-celery==3.1.16
- celery==3.1.16
- psycopg2==2.5.5 (I used also psycopg2==2.5.4)

```
[2015-07-19 11:27:49,488: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Task myapp.parse_items[63fc40eb-c0d6-46f4-a64e-acce8301d29a] INTERNAL ERROR: InterfaceError('connection already closed',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mo/Work/python/pb-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 284, in trace_task
    uuid, retval, SUCCESS, request=task_request,
  File "/home/mo/Work/python/pb-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 248, in store_result
    request=request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mo/Work/python/pb-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/backends/database.py", line 29, in _store_result
    traceback=traceback, children=self.current_task_children(request),
  File "/home/mo/Work/python/pb-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/managers.py", line 42, in _inner
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mo/Work/python/pb-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/managers.py", line 181, in store_result
    'meta': {'children': children}})
  File "/home/mo/Work/python/pb-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/managers.py", line 87, in update_or_create
    return get_queryset(self).update_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/home/mo/Work/python/pb-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/managers.py", line 70, in update_or_create
    obj, created = self.get_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/home/mo/Work/python/pb-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 376, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**lookup), False
  File "/home/mo/Work/python/pb-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 304, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/home/mo/Work/python/pb-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 77, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/mo/Work/python/pb-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 857, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/home/mo/Work/python/pb-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 220, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/home/mo/Work/python/pb-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 713, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/home/mo/Work/python/pb-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 785, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/home/mo/Work/python/pb-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 160, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/home/mo/Work/python/pb-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 134, in _cursor
    return self.create_cursor()
  File "/home/mo/Work/python/pb-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/mo/Work/python/pb-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 134, in _cursor
    return self.create_cursor()
  File "/home/mo/Work/python/pb-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 137, in create_cursor
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
InterfaceError: connection already closed
```

Comment: Can you show the problematic code?

Answer (score 23):

> Unfortunately this is a problem with django + psycopg2 + celery combo.
>   It's an old and unsolved problem.
>
> Take a look on this thread to understand:
>   https://github.com/celery/django-celery/issues/121
>
> Basically, when celery starts a worker, it forks a database connection
>   from django.db framework. If this connection drops for some reason, it
>   doesn't create a new one. Celery has nothing to do with this problem
>   once there is no way to detect when the database connection is dropped
>   using django.db libraries. Django doesn't notifies when it happens,
>   because it just start a connection and it receives a wsgi call (no
>   connection pool). I had the same problem on a huge production
>   environment with a lot of machine workers, and sometimes, these
>   machines lost connectivity with postgres server.
>
> I solved it putting each celery master process under a linux
>   supervisord handler and a watcher and implemented a decorator that
>   handles the psycopg2.InterfaceError, and when it happens this function
>   dispatches a syscall to force supervisor restart gracefully with
>   SIGINT the celery process.

Edit:

Found a better solution. I implemented a celery task baseclass like this:

```
from django.db import connection
import celery

class FaultTolerantTask(celery.Task):
    """ Implements after return hook to close the invalid connection.
    This way, django is forced to serve a new connection for the next
    task.
    """
    abstract = True

    def after_return(self, *args, **kwargs):
        connection.close()

@celery.task(base=FaultTolerantTask)
def my_task():
    # my database dependent code here
```

I believe it will fix your problem too.

Comment: hi emanuelcds, can you share example? facing same issue and would help to see sample code. Thanks

Comment: I got a better solution yesterday. I will implement and check if it works properly. Once it worked, I will edit this answer and let you know. But basicaly, you can use a base class on a celery task by using the 'base' argument o @app.task. I will implement something to restart the db connection if it fails. I will keep you posted here.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same exception from a daemon python script which is using Django ORM to access a db (Django==1.9.5, psycopg2==2.6.1). If PostgreSQL gets restarted while the daemon is running (or a db connection becomes invalid for some other reason), the db connection never gets recreated. It is possible to catch every possible db exception and forcibly reset the connection, but this is a big hack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447497. I'd love to see a general solution to address this.

Comment: There is no general solution. In your case, just use a try except block catching a django.db.utils.Error, closing the django.db.connection like the way I did on my edited code, and retry the entire process again.

Answer (score 11):

Guys and [emanuelcds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/381201/emanuelcds),

I had the same problem, now I have updated my code and created a new loader for celery:

```
from djcelery.loaders import DjangoLoader
from django import db

class CustomDjangoLoader(DjangoLoader):
    def on_task_init(self, task_id, task):
        """Called before every task."""
        for conn in db.connections.all():
            conn.close_if_unusable_or_obsolete()
        super(CustomDjangoLoader, self).on_task_init(task_id, task)
```

This of course if you are using djcelery, it will also require something like this in the settings:

```
CELERY_LOADER = 'myproject.loaders.CustomDjangoLoader'
os.environ['CELERY_LOADER'] = CELERY_LOADER
```

I still have to test it, I will update.

Answer (score 5):

If you are running into this when running tests, then you can either change the test to TransactionTestCase class instead of TestCase or add the mark `pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)`. This kept my db connection alive from creation of the pytest-celery fixtures to the database calls.

Github issue - https://github.com/Koed00/django-q/issues/167

For context, I am using pytest-celery with `celery_app` and `celery_worker` as fixtures in my tests. I am also trying to hit the test db in the tasks referenced in these tests.

If someone would explain switching to transaction=True keeps it open, that would be great!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).